# "expected ')' before numeric constant" when calling sem_init

Tags: c, posix, semaphore

Doing an OS programming assignment using semaphores and POSIX threads. Here's my code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

sem_t mutex, to_b, to_a;

int main()
{
    // Initialize semaphores
    sem_init(&mutex, 0, 1);
    sem_init(&to_b, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&to_a 0, 0);
}
```

Compiling with `gcc main.c -lpthread` I get:

```
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:11:24: error: expected ')' before numeric constant
main.c:11:24: error: too few arguments to function 'sem_init'
/usr/include/semaphore.h:37:12: note: declared here
```

Any idea what could cause this? I'm definitely calling sem_init correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a comma missing in

```
sem_init(&to_a 0, 0);
```

It should be

```
sem_init(&to_a, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sem_init(&to_a 0, 0);
              ^
```

You're just missing a comma.

Answer (score 0):

So look at the error: `main.c:11:24: error: too few arguments to function 'sem_init'`

Line 11 has a problem, it has "too few arguments". You're making the same call on line 10 and 9 right? but no such error, so take a careful look, character for character between line 10 and line 11.

You'll see you missed a comma:

```
sem_init(&to_b, 0, 0);
sem_init(&to_a 0, 0);  // see it's shorter?
```

Should be:

```
sem_init(&to_a, 0, 0);
```